# Photoshop jsx Set activeDocument to currently open document

Tags: photoshop, jsx

How do you set the `activeDocument` to the currently open document in Photoshop jsx ?

Answer (score 4):

if you have only one document open in photoshop, `app.activeDocument` is the "activeDocument"
if you want the "active document" to be a different document you have to reference it as follows

consider you have two documents already open "picture1.jpg" and picture2.jpg"
you would set each one to be the active document as follows

```
app.activeDocument = app.documents[0] // set to picture1.jpg
app.activeDocument = app.documents[1] // set to picture2.jpg
```

the indexing (the numbers) refer to the open documents and start from the left most document tab([0]) and the end document tab ([n]) n being the document relative to the first counting from 0
need any more help just ask
sorry i am assuming your are new to programming.

Comment: `app.activeDocument` will always refer to the top-most (foreground) open document, even if the user switches them manually in photoshop, activeDocument will change too. If you want to do it in the script the array of open documents is `app.documents`. If you want to change the active document you can assign it like this: `app.activeDocument = app.documents[0]` I've tested this and it works.